# Get administrative borders with Overpass QL

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, overpass-api

I try to download the state borders of France (a few dozen states, not big data). Indeed I look for borders I can upload in my postgres database to localize POIs. OpenstreetMap seemed to be the good data source so I have tried to learn Overpass QL but it seems harder than I thought to do so... After some wiki reading I came to this:

```
way["name:en"="France"];
way["type"="boundary"];
way["boundary"="administrative"];
way["admin_level"="4"];
```

But the query endless runs... I am not sure about the query I made, is this the good syntax ? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several issues with your query:

1. Administrative boundaries are frequently modeled as relations, rather than ways in OSM. So querying for ways `way[...]` will not return the result you're looking for.
2. To fetch elements which have have several tags, you need to combine them like `[key1=value1][key2=value2]`. You current query would query ALL ways WORLDWIDE with `type=boundary` and then again WORLDWIDE all ways with `admin_level=4`. Obviously this is both very expensive and not what you're looking for.
3. `out` statement is mandatory to return some result. In your case, the query would in fact run, but it would never return anything.

My recommendation is to use the following query instead:

```
rel["ISO3166-2"~"^FR"]
   [admin_level=4]
   [type=boundary]
   [boundary=administrative];
out geom;
```

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/lnv

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I need

Comment: I pushed a little forward and tried to get all the city boundaries from France. Based on what you told me for states, I tried the same but with level_admin=8 for cities. But there is no ISO3166 tag for city boundaries, actualy no country tag at all in the admin_level 8 boundaries. How can I search for all city boundaries of a specific country? Thanks!

    rel["ISO3166-2"~"^FR"]
       [admin_level=8]
       [type=boundary]
       [boundary=administrative];
    out geom;

Comment: @ThomasPerrin do you solve this? I'm looking for a way to do the same

Comment: I @David, no I didn't, I gave up this way to do it, I am now using the awesome website "OSM Boundaries 4.2" https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/, it provides all the administrative boundaries of the world with an API service to download data

Comment: @ThomasPerrin has it some documetation and an API to get the data?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes it has, click on the "info/help" button on the upper right, it will show you a new panel with everything. There is an API (lower panel). Here is the link to the documentation: https://wambachers-osm.website/index.php/projekte/internationale-administrative-grenzen/boundaries-map-4-2-english-version.

Comment: To test the API simply select an administrative border in the browser of the left panel, in the lower panel select API then click on the EXPORT button

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query. Adjust the admin level to your needs. Be careful while using the browser as it may return huge data. For me, it was 60 MB.

```
area["boundary"="administrative"][admin_level=2]["name:en"=France] ->.boundaryarea;
rel(area.boundaryarea)[boundary=administrative][admin_level~"^[3-5]$"];
out geom;
```